# Update Textarea from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I want to update textarea from controller after i found some result and page should not be reload. Is there any solution for this?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        return View();
   }

    public JsonResult SolveProblems(Problem[] array){

            Solution sol=new Solution(array);

            sol.OnSolutionFound+=sol_OnSolutionFound;
            sol.OnTaskComplete+=sol_OnTaskComplete;

            sol.Start();
            return Json("Process started");
    }

    private void sol_OnSolutionFound(object sender, SolutionFoundEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here i want update textarea 
    }

    private void sol_OnTaskComplete(object sender,  SolutionCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Here i want show process is finished  
    }       
}
```

This is my html page. which contains some code and one textarea

```
..... some code....

<textarea class="form-control" id="ResultDisplay"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btnSolve" class="btn btn-primary">Solve</button>
```

this is my javascript file

```
 function GetProblems(){
     ...code... 
     return array; 
 }

 $("#btnSolve").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/SolveProblems",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(GetProblems()),
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Unexpected error occurs!")
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: inside your `success` write something like `$("#ResultDisplay").val(response)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen SolveProblems is run under main thread and Start will run under another thread so main thread just start Start method  and after that it require time to found a single solution so   $("#ResultDisplay").val(response) is not solution

Comment: No, not the way you are currently coding. You need to think in terms of request-response for MVC applications.  You make a request, you get a response.  You're trying to: make request-start backgroundprocess-get request's response-*then* get backgroundprocess response.  There's no request matching the backgroundprocess response so nowhere for it to go.   You have (at least) two choices: easiest is to make a second request via ajax that does the background task - which no longer needs to be a background task as it will run under a second request.  The other option is to refactor to use SignalR.

Comment: On second view, you're already making an ajax call for the SolveProblems - so just don't make it a background task and you're good to go.

Comment: @freedomn-m Main problem is that i want show immediately result when it found, not wait for the all process to finished

Comment: `$.ajax({..}); alert("Process started");`

Comment: I'm guessing your real `SolveProblems` action does/returns more than just returns "Process Started" - otherwise there's no point to it.

Comment: You might like to have a look at SignalR.   It allows you to communicate "directly" between your server-side code (a hub, but essentially the same as a controller) and javascript.  You can easily pass back status/progress information this way.  Have a look at https://www.asp.net/signalr and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Comment: 'SolveProblems' is use for just to start solution process nothing else @freedomn-m

Comment: I see - you want a UI update whenever `sol_OnSolutionFound()` is called.  SignalR is your best bet and this scenario is pretty much what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have use SignalR and solve my problem as [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) told me to do

I need to create a Hub by using i can send data when `sol_OnSolutionFound` is fired.

Here is my Hub

```
public class SolutionHub : Hub
{
    public void SolutionFound(string Solution)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SolutionHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(Solution);
    }
}
```

Add section in Index.cshtml

```
@section scripts {
<!--Script references. -->
<!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.solutionHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (Solution) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $("#ResultDisplay").append(Solution);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

and finally need to call `SolutionFound` when `sol_OnSolutionFound` is fired.

```
private void sol_OnSolutionFound(object sender, SolutionFoundEventArgs e)
{
    SolutionHub Hub=new SolutionHub();
    Hub.SolutionFound(e.Solution);
}
```